# How many template elements can I have in the DOM?

Tags: html, angular

I have just started with angular2 and the concept / architecture of how they implement templates using `*ngFor`, `*ngIf` and defining of my own `<template>` elements is new to me.

What I would like to know though *(because it wasn't broached in the documentation)*, is that are there any performance hits to defining huge quantities of templates?

For example;

```
<div *ngFor="let screen of screens" [ngSwitch]="screen.templateID"> <!-- huge loop -->
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="0">{{screen.id}} | {{screen.templateURL}}</template>
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="1">{{screen.id}} | {{screen.templateURL}}</template>
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="1">{{screen.id}} | {{screen.templateURL}}</template>
</div>
```

Which could hypothetically generate thousands of templates, is it *"acceptable"* to generate so many templates or should I add more logic in to reduce the amount being instantiated?

Comment: I guess you'll need to do your own benchmarks. I don't see any obvious reason why it would be a problem. `<template>` elements are processed at build time by Angular2 and not added to the DOM before they are stamped in some way (ngForTemplate, createdEmbeddedView, ngSwitchCase, ...)
"should I add more logic in to reduce the amount being instantiated" I don't think this can be answered generically.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @GünterZöchbauer - I ended up using routes in the end which completely mitigated this issue. Whilst I have your attention, can you please look at my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218239/viewchild-is-undefined) on Angular2, when i was researching this issue, your attribution to the github issue on this topic was very insightful and so fingers crossed, you will easily see what is causing my drama. Thanks for your time.